# Attempting to create a Jukebox in Java

Tags: java

I am taking a class for Java and I am trying to create a "Jukebox" in Java that will play three songs based on the user's command. I am attempting to do this with multiple classes, so I'll make sure to put in both. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class JukeBox
{
    JukeBox(String[] playList, String[] fileList)
    {
    }

    public int displayMenu() throws IOException
    {
      String token = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      File fileName = new File("PlayList.txt");
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
      while (inFile.hasNext())
      {
         token = inFile.nextLine( );
         System.out.println (token);
      }
      return in.nextInt();
    }

    public void playSong(int choice)throws IOException
    {
      File fileName = new File("PlayList.txt");
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
      if(choice == 1)
      {
         SimpleSound song1 = new SimpleSound("Radioative.wav");
         song1.play();
      }
      else if(choice == 2)
      {
          SimpleSound song2 = new SimpleSound("Rope.wav");
          song2.play();
      }
      else if(choice == 3)
      {
          SimpleSound song3 = new SimpleSound("Same Love.wav");
          song3.play();
      }

      else if(choice == 0)
      {
          inFile.close();
      }
    }
}
```

And here is the "file handler" and tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
class FileHandler
{
    private String[] playList = new String[7];
    private String[] fileList = new String[7];
    private String file;

    FileHandler(String f) 
    {
        file = f;
    }

    public void readFile() throws IOException
    {
        int index = 0;
        File fileName = new File(file);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
            playList[index] = inFile.nextLine();
            fileList[index] = inFile.nextLine();
            index++;
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

    public String[] getPlayList()
    {
        return playList;
    }

    public String[] getFileList()
    {
        return fileList;
    }
}//end of class 

public class JukeBoxTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int choice = 0;
        FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("PlayList.txt");
        fileHandler.readFile();
        String [] playList = fileHandler.getPlayList();
        String [] fileList = fileHandler.getFileList();

        JukeBox myPod = new JukeBox(playList, fileList);
        choice = myPod.displayMenu();
        myPod.playSong(choice);

    }
}
```

So, I compile my program and I receive no syntax errors; however, when it runs, I receive the error

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found (in.java.util.Scanner)

And so, that highlights

> String [] fileList = fileHandler.getFileList();

I am pretty lost and still not one hundred percent positive if this will run the way I want it to. However, I am trying to take it one step at a time and fix this problem first. Please help. Also, here is what the text file looks like that I am using:

```
        Dylan's PlayList
********************************************
<1> Imagine Dragons     Radioactive
<2> Foo Fighters        Rope
<3> Macklemore          Same Love
********************************************
Enter your choice (1-3 or 0 to quit):
```

I also already have my music files saved as a .wav, ready to play.

Comment: Is your last code sample really the format of your text file? Or do you have something more structured?

Comment: You get this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: error when you are accessing an index of an array which is greater than the actual length of the array .. what does PlayList.txt file contain  ?

Comment: Arthur: Yes, the last code sample is the same exact way it is formatted in my text file.

Comment: Sandeep: The last code sample shows the PlayList.txt file

Comment: Just count how many lines are there in your file.Probably you have more than 6 lines in your file...

Comment: Sandeep: I did what you said and that error stopped. However, I am getting a new error. Could you check my edit and see maybe why it could be happening?

Comment: If you use a ``case`` statement you could eliminate the ``else if`` and format your code to fit without scrolling.